# some http requests don't appear in chrome developer tools

Tags: python, google-chrome, web-crawler, autologin

I want to login a website such as [zhihu](http://www.zhihu.com), [weibo](http://weibo.com). But after I post login data in chrome, I find that the http request which relates to login appears for a very short time and then disappears in the section *Network* of chrome developer tools so that I couldn't analyze the login request.

Though I can login these website using python for the time being, I want to know why the login request doesn't persist in the section *Network* of chrome developer tools

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should turn on **Preserve Log upon Navigation** before you login.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It really is! What technique is used to achieve such an effect when doing web development?

Comment: @flyer, Sorry. I don't understand what you are asking in your comment.

Comment: I'm sorry that my English is not good. I want to know how to achieve such an effect that the login request doesn't persist in the section *Network* of chrome developer tools, which I have observed in my question.

Comment: @flyer, My English is not good, neither. I don't know what you asked. How about post a separated question?

Comment: Thank you very much :D I'll post a new question to describe my problem.